# How to get the headers from the API on which the application is running using c#

Tags: model-view-controller, http-headers

** the application is hosted on server and  the API if prodding the headers. I want to read that headers to get the user name (who is accessing the application)**

Comment: Include more details. Is it you that are making API calls, or clients and you want to have them as statistic?

Comment: For each user the headers will change like username (who is accessing the server ) so I have to read that username from controller to compare with the user in the database if that matches then it should provide access to the application.